# CSS - Center Font-awesome icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How can I center the FontAwesome icons inside the squares?

At this point all of the icons, except from facebook icon are beeing placed more or less to the right, especially the soundcloude icon.

I have been using the "w3schools - Social Media Buttons" example, it seems like this issue occure when the squares are scaled down.

```css
.fa {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 3px; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 7.5px;
  height: 7.5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 7.5px !important;
}

.fa {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  color: #282828;
}


.fa-facebook:hover {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.fa-youtube:hover {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.fa-instagram:hover {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.fa-soundcloud:hover {
  background: #ff5500;
  color: white;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-soundcloud"></a>
```

Comment: You should upgrade to font-awesome 5, if you can. :)

Comment: padding: 15px and width:7.5px ??!! ... remove width and height and line-height and they will be centred

Comment: I don't think you should customize .fa if you're using font awesome < 5, and if upgrading to 5, I belive .fa is deprecated... Also, if using icons with varying widths, you can use .fa-fw (fixed width)...

Comment: FYI: I believe .fa-fw is the same as: `width: 1.25em; text-align: center;`

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use <1px values to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kill the unnecessary padding (which leaves no room for the icons) and let the `width`/`height`/`line-height` of the elements determine their layout.

Before:

```
padding: 15px;
width: 7.5px; 
height: 7.5px;
line-height: 7.5px !important;
```

After:

```
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px !important;
```

You can also remove some redundant styles from your `:hover` states.

Live example:

```css
.fa {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px !important;
}

.fa {
  background: #F0F0F0;
  color: #282828;
}

.fa:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.fa-facebook:hover {
  background: #3B5998;
}

.fa-youtube:hover {
  background: #bb0000;
}

.fa-instagram:hover {
  background: #125688;
}

.fa-soundcloud:hover {
  background: #ff5500;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-soundcloud"></a>
```

Comment: i would probably kill all the width and height and line height ... keeping padding is enough

Comment: @TemaniAfif How so? FontAwesome icons are not of uniform size, so each circle would be a different shape if you used only `padding`.

Comment: well maybe keep only the width then ;) the height should be the same for all

Comment: I would kill `line-height: inherit;` in `hover` too. Don't you ? What is it used for ?

Comment: line-height: inherit; in hover is gone

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's true. An alternate solution would be `padding: 7.5px 0; width: 30px;` and no `line-height` or `height` rule.

Comment: there was no need for all this in the future make a container with `display: flex` and then in the a tags make it `inline-flex` and `justify-content: center`

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can centered the icons.
I have added my code snippet.
Suggesting, please do not write css for class `fa` the. please add new class for the same

```css
.decoration-fa{
    padding:15px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    color: #282828;
    width:18px;
    height:18px;    
}

.decoration-fa.fa-facebook:hover {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.decoration-fa.fa-youtube:hover {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.decoration-fa.fa-instagram:hover {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}

.fa-soundcloud:hover {
  background: #ff5500;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook decoration-fa"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube decoration-fa"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram decoration-fa"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-soundcloud decoration-fa"></a>
```